# Word Splitting with Double Quotes vs Having Quotes

Tags: bash

I have a file `requirements.txt` containing dependencies for future installation.
The file simply has one name on each line:

```
$cat requirements.txt 
pandas
numpy
...
```

Some part of my actual code looks like this:

```
packages=$(cat "requirements.txt") || exit
```

When I do `echo $packages` instead of `"$packages"`, I get the following result

```
echo $packages
pandas numpy ...
```

VS

```
echo "$packages"
pandas
numpy
...
```

I am having difficulty understanding how splitting actually happens. For me, it looks like the unquoted version doesn't split the string, while double quotes do something strange and print the result line by line, even though they are supposed to prevent the splitting(that is, I expected the result to be a single line) Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `packages` includes multiple lines, separated by newline characters - when you echo the quoted expansion, that's exactly what you see, since the whole multiline string is passed as a single argument to the `echo` command.

When you echo the *unquoted* expansion, it is subject to word splitting (and glob expansion - although that's not relevant here since your input doesn't contain any globbing characters). Word splitting is based on the value of the `IFS` variable, which by default consists of space, tab ***and newline***. Each `IFS`-delimited token is passed as a separate argument to `echo`, which outputs each of them in turn, separated by a single space.

Further reading:

- [Expansion of a shell variable and effect of glob and split on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109074/65304)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yesterday I did figure out that my string had newline characters. Just to be 100 % sure, all word splitting does is just separate the string based on the separator present in `$IFS` (just like python's `split()` function)? I am still unsure if it happens for each separator separately or only once for a single one. For example, if my string had both spaces and newlines would it separate it once or twice? (assuming the standard `$IFS`). Sorry if you already answered this part but I always want to be certain I got it right

Comment: @Alex.Kh if your input contained spaces as well as newlines (for example, a package named `foo bar`) then the unquoted expansion would split that as well - so echo would receive separate arguments `foo` and `bar`. You wouldn't care with `echo`, but if you were trying to run an actual command on the result, it would likely fail. That's why constructs like `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done <file` are preferred over `for i in $(cat file); do ...; done` for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do realize now why people mostly recommend the `while` loop for reading files compared to commands like `cat`